# convert existing array to a new one?

Tags: php

In my manipulate I got an array contain data like this:

```
 $A = Array
    (
        [0] => 0302 sa
           [1] => 0602 sdsa
           [2] => 0602 sada
           [3] => 0802 sadasdasd
        [4] => 0302 sada
           [5] => 0602 saa
           [6] => 0602 sdad
           [7] => 0802 sds
        [8] => 0302 sda
           [9] => 0602 sdada
           [10] => 0602 sada
           [11] => 0802 sdada
        [12] => 0302 sda
           [13] => 0602 sdads
           [14] => 0602 saddas
           [15] => 0802 sadas
    )
```

the output will be the new array

```
 $B = Array
        (//03
        [0] => array( 
                    [0] => 0602 sdsa,//06
                    [1] => 0602 sada //06
        )
        //03
        [1] => array(
                 [0] => 0602 saa,//06
                 [1] => 0602 sdad //06
               )
                //03
        [2] => array(
                 [0] => 0602 sdada,//06
                 [1] => 0602 sada //06
          )
          //03
        [3] =>array(
                 [0] => 0602 sdads,//06
                 [1] => 0602 saddas//06
        )
    )
```

Try

```
function TODO($A){
  $B = array();
  foreach ($A as $key=>$line){
 if(substr($line,0,2)=="03"){
     $B[] = ???
   }
}
```

Who can help me to solve this?

Comment: So you want a new subarray to be created anytime an item has the value of "03..."?

Comment: yes,03 will became the main array ,06 will be the elements of 03

Comment: What is the logic of data manipulation here? If x = xxx then assign it to y, if x2 = xxx2 then assign it to y2... Would you tell us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$B = array( );
foreach( $a as $line ) {
  if(substr($line,0,2)=="03"){
    if( isset( $tmpArray )) $B[] = $tmpArray;
    $tmpArray = array( );
  } else {
    if( !isset( $tmpArray ) continue;
    $tmpArray[] = $line;
  }
}
if( isset( $tmpArray )) $B[] = $tmpArray;
```

Just simple idea :-)

Comment: This will add the row with value `0802` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$B = array();
$flag = 0;
foreach ($A as $key=>$line){
        if($flag != 0) {
                if($flag == 1) {
                        $temp = array();
                        $temp[0] = $line;
                        $flag++;
                } else {
                        $temp[1] = $line;
                        $B[] = $temp;
                        $flag = 0;
                }
        }
        if(substr($line,0,2)=="03"){
                $flag = 1;
        }
}
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/homdI)

Note: I'm assuming the two `06`'s will immediately follow the `03`.

Comment: if I added  15 => '0602 Added1',
 16 => '0602 Added2' I have a problems.Please look at http://www.ideone.com/homdI  the elements have added.

Comment: @python: Your intent is not very clear. Do you want to add all `06` (no matter how many) after a `06` ?